# Generate special JS for each modal Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm making shop script but I got problem. I made function which show all items from mysql and add to it modal but I don't know how to add JS to each modal so I can buy item without reloading page, only on modal. This is code of item creating:

```
    function create_item($id, $imgid, $title, $desc, $cost, $smscode, $smsnumber)
{
    echo '
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <span class="pull-right title-itemshop">'. $title .'</span><img class="pull-left"src="id/'. $imgid .'.png"/>
                    <br/><hr class="hr-itemshop"/>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger form-control" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'. $id .'">Zobacz więcej &raquo;</a>
                </div>
                 <div id="'. $id .'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title-item">'. $title .'</h4>  
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>'. $desc .'</p>
                        <p>Aby kupić usługę wyślij SMS o treści <b>'. $smscode .'</b> na numer <b>'. $smsnumber .'</b> a w odpowiedzi otrzymasz kod, który należy podać w formularzu poniżej.</p>   
                          <form class="kupno'; echo $id; echo '"> 
                          <input id="nick" name="nick"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick osoby">
                          <input id="kod" name="kod"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kod z SMS zwrotnego">
                          <input id="id" name="id"  type="hidden" value="'. $id .'">
                          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Kup Teraz!" id="submit'; echo $id; echo '">
                          </form>

                      </div>
                    </div>


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    ';
}
```

And this how look mcbuy.php, it's only for testing pursposes so I just put save data from POST to file.

```
<?php
$id = strip_tags(trim($_POST['id']));
$user = strip_tags(trim($_POST['nick']));
$kod = strip_tags(trim($_POST['kod']));
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "$id$user$kod\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

How can I generate each JS for each item in shop. In mcbuy.php i will check id of item from post data and get another from database

Comment: I'm not really understanding your problem. Can you describe what you want a bit more detailed? :)

Comment: I have a shop page and i have function which generate items on page(create_item in loop but it's not important). When I left just only <form class="abcd" name="abcd"> And i press submit button i will get in POST all inputs from alll items because they will have the same id(form). How can I make modal javascript separately?